# Floating content seems to stack when duplicated - CSS

Tags: css, css-float, fluid-layout

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kd4De/2/ .

I have duplicated the content 3 times and as you can see it seems to stack `into` one another on each duplication. My intended effect is for each duplication to look exactly like the previous (all having the same width).

I have a feeling it's because I am only floating one `div` and not the other, but this is required to ensure fluid width of the non floating `div`.

How can I fix this to ensure consistency between each duplication WHILST keeping fluidity (i.e if I change the width of `.dynamo_shop_holder` to `90%` dynamically, the content dynamically changes to fit? I do not want to use JavaScript at all.

Thanks!

Comment: hard to say without seeing the css but a couple of things you can try.  add overflow: hidden to the div styles.  an alternate would be clear: both

Comment: I've linked to the fiddle which gives all HTML and CSS. I am clearing but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Unfortunately not everyone can go to jsfiddle.   That's why it is better to put the code here.   Try overflow:hidden

Comment: Thanks, `overflow:hidden` on the parent element seems to work, can you tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

```
overflow: hidden;
```

the overflow attribute tells the browser how to display content that goes beyond the bounds of the container.   Some browsers render the content strangely and assume that the parent div has a set height or if empty no height, causing the child or floated divs to appear outside and in your case stack.   Overflow hidden is supposed to hide anything that flows outside of the container, but in these cases it allows that parent container to recognize the content that should be within it and display correctly.

I can't see the jsfiddle so not sure what your display looks like, but often overflow: hidden or overflow:auto will allow the divs to correctly handle the contained content.